# Is it possible to run a query on an arbitrary set of values?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how I would construct a query against a series of values (rather than handling this programmatically in the business logic).

The specific desire is to pull from a table the rows that exist within given time frames.  So, in pseudo I'd like to do something like

```
set timeframes as ["'2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'",  "'2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28'" ,  "'2014-03-01' and '2014-03-31'", ... etc for the rest of the year];

select t , 
(select count(id) from users where registration_date between t)

from timeframes;
```

and this would result in a table that looks like

```
2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31  |   455
2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28  |   773
etc.
```

**EDIT**
To be clear, this example (with months) is just a sample of what I'm trying to do... In the real scenario I have, the list of criteria could be something entirely arbitrary, so, while I really appreciate the answers that utilize mysql constructs like the **MONTH()** method, that's not the real problem I'm looking to solve here.

Comment: you could use a temporary table and fill it with "insert into temptable (SELECT .....)"

Comment: You also could just select grouping by month number...

Comment: I'd recommend doing as @ITroubs suggested. The query for your exact results would be fairly complicated (or at any rate tough to read). The answer from ITroubs will give you the raw data, nicely summarized, and you can pretty it up in the business logic. If you need more than one year, just group and order by `YEAR(dateCol), MONTH(dateCol)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to help solve your problem the exact way proposed, but have managed to make a similar (I think) solution (**[here you may find SQL Fiddle for the below](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6fb759/5)**):

### Data structure

```
CREATE TABLE timeframes 
(
  tf_start DATE  NOT NULL,
  tf_end DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(tf_start, tf_end)  
);

CREATE TABLE users 
(
  id int primary key NOT NULL,
  registration_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO timeframes
VALUES
('2014-01-01' , '2014-01-31'),  
('2014-02-01' , '2014-02-28'),  
('2014-03-01' , '2014-03-31');


INSERT INTO users
VALUES
(455, '2014-01-14'),
(773, '2014-02-17');
```

### Queries

**To select users count within timeframe:**

```
select 
    CONCAT('''', DATE_FORMAT(t.tf_start, '%Y-%m-%d'), ''' and ''', DATE_FORMAT(t.tf_end, '%Y-%m-%d'), '''') AS tf, 
    (select count(id) from users where registration_date between t.tf_start AND t.tf_end) AS user_count
from 
    timeframes t;
```

Result:

```
TF                              |   USER_COUNT
==============================================
'2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'   |   1
'2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28'   |   1
'2014-03-01' and '2014-03-31'   |   0
```

**To join each user to timeframe to which `registration_date` belongs to:**

```
select 
  CONCAT('''', DATE_FORMAT(t.tf_start, '%Y-%m-%d'), ''' and ''', DATE_FORMAT(t.tf_end, '%Y-%m-%d'), '''') AS tf,
  users.id
from 
  timeframes t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users 
     ON users.registration_date between t.tf_start AND t.tf_end;
```

and result:

```
TF                              |   ID
===========================================
'2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'   |   455
'2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28'   |   773
'2014-03-01' and '2014-03-31'   |   (null)
```

I hope it helps some way.

Comment: wow... that's very elaborate... thanks.  I think that will work for me, I'll need to modify it to meet my actual - non date specific - needs, but I see what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad it helped :) As for your answers edit, the porblem stated is really curious - it would be very fine to find such dynamic criteria appliance solution, however, by now I have no idea how it could be achieved - I've tried with prepared statements, but seems not to fit - at least for now. Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(dateCol), 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE datecol BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31' 
GROUP BY MONTH(dateCol) 
ORDER BY MONTH(dateCol)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice on how to handle this specific issue, but my question was more about arbitrary groupings. In this case it happens to coincide with months but in principle the idea is to have an array of criteria based upon which to run rows of results.

Comment: depending on what language you use to query the database you can use an algorithm that generates the query to your liking